# How to add SharePoint Online PowerShell to Visual Studio Code and Cmder

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, office365, visual-studio-code, cmder

I installed **SharePoint Online PowerShell** to interact with Office 365 sites, I would like SharePoint Online PowerShell to be added as an option to **Visual Studio Code** terminal and also how to add it to **Cmder**?

Answer (score 0):

For [Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) install [`PowerShell Extension`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/docs/learning-powershell/using-vscode.md) which provides PowerShell language support for Visual Studio Code.

Once [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038) is installed, you can write and debug SharePoint PowerShell scripts using Visual Studio Code.

**Results**

PS script debugging

[image]